# How Access of global data member and member function in a class?

Tags: c++

I have declare a global data and global function,when i try to access in a class compiler throw error as "  i cannot appear in constant expression",why?

```
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int i=20;

  void fn()
  { 
    cout<<" I am outside class"<<endl;
  }

  class a
  {
      public: 

        int x= ::i;  // error is  i cannot appear in constant expression

        void accessGlobal()
        {

           ::fn();      //fn() is being called
        }
  };

  int main()
  {
     a obj;
     obj.accessGlobal();
  }
```

Comment: What compiler ? Compiles here : http://ideone.com/ig4sXo

Comment: `int x= ::i;` in C++, you cannot declare and initialize a member variable in the same line. Initialization should occur in the constructor.

Comment: your example is legal in C++11 standard, which introduces non-static data member initializers, but in C++98 standard compilation will result in error.

Comment: @crashmstr what ? Its allowed since c++11

Comment: @quantdev I am using gcc compiler version 4.3.12 sorry but on gcc i it is throwing error

Comment: @user3784175 : add -std=c++11 in your options and change to a more recent version of gcc (4.9+ now)

Comment: @crashmstr but inside function is possible?                      void accessGlobal()
        {
            int x=::i //but this is possible how?
           ::fn();      //fn() is being called
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not related with global variables, but with class member initialization.

What you are trying to do with `x` is *in-class member initialization* and is supported in C++ since C++11, standard section §12.6.2 :

> In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member or
>   base class is not designated by a mem-initializer-id (including the
>   case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the constructor
>   has no ctor-initializer) and the entity is not a virtual base class of
>   an abstract class (10.4), then
>
> - if the entity is a non-static data member that has a brace-or-equal-initializer, the entity is initialized as specified in
>     8.5;

---

**Solution :**

- Use a C++11 compiler and add support for C++11 (-std=c++11). See it working [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c4726156b3a5f2b).
- If you really can't, do the usual and provide a constructor to initialize your member :

**Example :**

```
a() : x(::i) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use C++11 standard to compile this code, in previous standards it is forbidden to define non-static variable inside the definition of the class (constructor of the class should do it). Following the old standard you can also try to add `static` keyword before variable declaration and initialize it after the class definition:

```
class a {
    public:
        static int x;
};
int a::x = ::i;
```

Comment: Yes, it is not, but it depends on the situation whenever it would fit the expectations of the programmer. This way you can initialize the variable like in the example, but it would become static for the class.